# The Workbench Drools project does not work after closing or recompiling

Tags: drools, rules, rule-engine, kie-workbench, drools-flow

I deploy the Drools workbench through a Docker container. And after deploying it and entering the interface through the browser, I configure the rules and processes.
When generating a rule using the "Guided rule" option of the Drools Workbench we add the conditions and the rule is generated correctly. The "Model" tab is displayed correctly and in the "Source" tab the rule code has been generated.
Pressing "Save" saves the rule correctly. And when compiling and deploying the project everything works fine.
[The rules are right and the project works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2VHA.jpg)
Afterwards, if I close the browser tab or stop the Docker container, and re-enter the interface the rules change format and don't work anymore. The same rule as before now has the lines joined together and the source code has also changed. As a result the project does not compile and does not work anymore:
[The rules are formatted differently and do not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpNNI.jpg)

Comment: "Do not work", "does not compile" -- these are very vague problems. If it does not compile, what are the errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.